# Javascript widget that shows the balance of a particular address

Tags: api

Is there an embeddable javascript widget (perhaps using blockchain.info API) that can show information about a specific Bitcoin address?

Like current balance, total incoming, outgoing, and latest transactions?

Comment: Unfortunately, bitcoinbox.ru is dependent on blockexplorer.com, and when blockexplorer.com is broken, so is bitcoinbox.ru. It queries
http://blockexplorer.com/q/addressbalance/1TBZjmXho6mdGhoESaMV2svtqJXYtWfEp/ and represents that text as an image. Compare the above to my final balance at http://blockchain.info/address/1TBZjmXho6mdGhoESaMV2svtqJXYtWfEp and you can tell if blockexplorer is working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a third party service that creates an img:

Balance:

- http://bitcoinbox.ru/display/graph.php?btcaddress=1PC9aZC4hNX2rmmrt7uHTfYAS3hRbph4UN&type=balance

Total received at the address:

- http://bitcoinbox.ru/display/graph.php?btcaddress=1PC9aZC4hNX2rmmrt7uHTfYAS3hRbph4UN